# Add to favorites using retrofit in Android?

Tags: android, retrofit2, android-toolbar

I have a toolbar with a favorite item . I want to add a property when the fav icon in toolbar is clicked by calling the api which has body param as user_id and property_id[image: Api for adding property to fav]
I have made a utility function to do so but I am not able to do :
My function:

```
public class APIUtilityfunctions {

private static final String TAG = "APIUtilityFunctions";
public static int twoHrsMilliseconds = 120000;
public static int fiveHrsMilliseconds = 300000;
public ApiInterface apiInterface ;

public static void addFavouriteProperty(final Context context, int user_id, int property_id) {


    Favourites favourites = new Favourites();
    favourites.setUserId(user_id);
    favourites.setPropertyId(user_id);
    Session session = new Session(context);

    ApiInterface apiInterface = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
    Call<List<Property>> call = apiInterface.addToFav(session.getJwtToken(), favourites);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Property>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Property>> call, Response<List<Property>> response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: " + response.body());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Property>> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
}
public static void setUserToSession(final Context context, int user_id) {
    ApiInterface apiInterface=ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);

    final Session session = new Session(context);

    Call<User> call =apiInterface.getUser(session.getJwtToken(),user_id);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {
            if (response.code() == 200) {
                User user = response.body();
                    session.setUserName(user.getName());

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable t) {
        }
    });
}
```

}

I have a session class to get the user_id 
My session Class:

```
public class Session {
private SharedPreferences sp;
private SharedPreferences.Editor spe;
Context context;
    int id;

public Session(Context cntx) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.context = cntx;
    sp = context.getSharedPreferences("MyData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    spe = sp.edit();
}


public void setUserID(int userID) {
    sp.edit().putInt("UserID", userID).apply();
}

public int getUserID() {
   return sp.getInt("",id);
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    sp.edit().putString("UserName", userName).commit();
}

public String getUserName() {
    return sp.getString("UserName", "");
}

public String getJwtToken() {
    String token = sp.getString("token", "");
    if (token == null || token.isEmpty()) {
        token =  "Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJleHAiOjIxNzc0NTI3OTksImlhdCI6MTUxNjAyMjk5OSwiaXNzIjoiQmFzb2JhYXMgTmVwYWwiLCJuYmYiOjE1MTYwMjI5OTksImp0aSI6Ikd1ZXN0VG9rZW4iLCJzdWIiOjB9.QikmNgBYmqch5HREGFEpUs4Xk3x-zFfDg5mhYJO7jM8";
    }
    return token;
}

public void setJwtToken(String token) {
    sp.edit().putString("token", token).apply();
}

public Date getExpiresAt() {

    String token =  "Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJleHAiOjIxNzc0NTI3OTksImlhdCI6MTUxNjAyMjk5OSwiaXNzIjoiQmFzb2JhYXMgTmVwYWwiLCJuYmYiOjE1MTYwMjI5OTksImp0aSI6Ikd1ZXN0VG9rZW4iLCJzdWIiOjB9.QikmNgBYmqch5HREGFEpUs4Xk3x-zFfDg5mhYJO7jM8";
    JWT jwt = new JWT(token);
    Date expiresAt = jwt.getExpiresAt();
    Toast.makeText(context, expiresAt.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.d("Expires At ", expiresAt.toString());
    return expiresAt;
}
```

}

I want to add the property to fav when a user clicks the fav icon in the property details page:

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
    JsonObject favourites=new JsonObject();
    favourites.addProperty("user_id", user_id);
    favourites.addProperty("property_id", user_id);
```

instead of

```
    Favourites favourites = new Favourites();
    favourites.setUserId(user_id);
    favourites.setPropertyId(user_id);
```

and in `addToFav()` inside `ApiInterface`, change the parameter for the body abject as `Call<JsonObject> addToFav(@Body JsonObject body);`

NOTE : pass `getJwtToken` also to `addToFav()`

EDIT : First of all create a menu resource `menu_item.xml` like this

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_fav"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/fav_icon"
    android:title="Favourite"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

Then inflate it in your layout like this

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_item, menu);
return true;
}
```

Then to handle click for menu item,

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
switch (item.getItemId()) {
  case R.id.action_fav:
    callApi();
    return true;
  default:
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }
  }
```

The function `callApi();` should perform api call to post your user_id and property_id

Comment: How do i make the toolbar i.e fav item in it execute the function when the  fav item in the toolbar is pressed?